# Is $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to a}\text{sgn}(f(x))$ always equal to $\text{sgn}\left(\displaystyle\lim_{x\to a}f(x)\right)$?

Tags: calculus, limits

Take this limit for example:$$\lim_{x\to0^+}\text{sgn}(x^{-\ln x})\\\text{sgn}(x):=
\begin{cases}
-1\quad&x\lt0\\
0\quad&x=0\\
1\quad&x\gt0
\end{cases}$$
Now, it can be shown that this limit has a value of $0$, however, this makes the assumption that$$\lim_{x\to a}\text{sgn}(f(x))=\text{sgn}(\lim_{x\to a}f(x))$$and my question is, is this always true, or when is this false?

For context, I was finding limits such as $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0^+}\text{sgn}(x^{-\ln x})$,  $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to1^+}\text{sgn}(\ln(x)^{-\ln\ln x})$, and $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0^+}\text{sgn}\left(\frac{x^2+4x-45}{e^x\ln x}\right)$ and was confused by what I was finding.

Comment: Consider $f(x)=x$ and $x\to 0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\to0^+}\text{sgn}(x^{-\ln x}) = 1
\end{align*}
Not $0$. Because $x^{-\ln x} > 0$ for all $x > 0$. I will prove it by definition of right limit. If $\varepsilon > 0$, let
$\delta = \varepsilon$. If $0 < x - 0 < \delta$, then $x^{-\ln x} >0$, hence

\begin{align*}
\left\vert \text{sgn}(x^{-\ln x}) - 1 \right\vert = 0 < \varepsilon
\end{align*}

Although
\begin{align*}
\text{sgn}\left(\lim_{x\to0^+} x^{-\ln x}\right) = 0
\end{align*}
because is true that $\lim_{x\to0^+} x^{-\ln x} = 0$.

So the answer is no, it's not equal.